# how do I test component with state, and setState as prop with Vitest?

Tags: reactjs, testing, vitest

i just start learning how to write a test (react). But im not sure how to test with a component that required state and setState as a prop. I've seen other examples using jest.fn() but im not sure how it works (with vitest Mocking?)

For example I have a Popover component

```
//Popover.jsx
const Popover = ({ setShowPopover, setIsEditing, setInputDisabled }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        data-testid="edit-task-btn"
        onClick={() => {
          setIsEditing(true);
          setShowPopover(false);
          setInputDisabled(false);
        }}>
        Edit
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Popover.test.jsx

```
///Popover.test.jsx
it('renders correctly and handles Edit', () => {
  const setIsEditingMock = () => {
    true;
  };

  const setShowPopoverMock = () => {
    false;
  };

  const setInputDisabledMock = () => {
    false;
  };

  render(
    <Popover
      setIsEditing={setIsEditingMock}
      setShowPopover={setShowPopoverMock}
      setInputDisabled={setInputDisabledMock}
    />
  );

  screen.debug();

  const editButton = screen.getByTestId('edit-task-btn');
  expect(editButton).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

Currently, it doesnt even render Popover component properly.  This is the error I get

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="edit-task-btn"]

Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
<body>
  <div />
</body>
```

Does anyone have any example for similar situation? or if anyone could tell me how could fix it? I tried to find examples on Youtube but there arent really much on working with state and setState props for Vitest.

Comment: I just ran the test using your code and the actual test is passing. Maybe there is something with your testing set up? Output from test: `renders correctly and handles Edit  <body>  <div> <div data-testid="edit-task-btn" >Edit</div></div></body>`

Comment: These are my imports `import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { expect, it,} from "vitest";`

Comment: @p7dxb Hi man, thanks for checking in. The given code snippet is nested in other component. It works when I recreated the component and ran it independently. Here's a brief nested component structure. App -> Task -> Popover. 
1. Task depends on fetching data (fetch tasks and map <Task>)
2. Inside <Task> , Popover conditionally render when showPopover is `true`
({showPopover && <Popover ... />})

I have some assumptions
1. Sth with async needs to be set in the test?
2. Setting conditional rendering in test (However I tried, but it still cant find element by [data-testid="edit-task-btn"])

Comment: Sorry I'm struggling to follow that comment, could you update the question to explain this part and what the test that fails looks like. As the provieded code passes the test I think it may be relevant to a solution? Thanks